# Hover (margin, z-index) button bug

Tags: html, css, hover, z-index, margin

I am building a page and I have small bug here.I can't click and hover on my button (buttons in div slide with class btn).I think a problem is in z-index or in margin on some element. But I don't know how to solve that.

Here is a page: http://project.gmwebs.cz/ .

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
}

body {
  background: url(img/background.jpg);
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(121, 0, 0);
}

h2 {
  color: #F2F2F2;
}

/* Menu */

.kolecko{
  width: 200px;
height: 100px;
background-color: #F2F2F2;
border-bottom-right-radius: 100px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 100px;
border: 10px solid rgb(121, 0, 0);
border-top: 0;
z-index: 3;
position: absolute;

-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
margin-top: 40px;
}

.logo {
  width: 160px;
  z-index: 4;
  position: absolute;
}


.menu-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

nav {
  height: 90px;
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
  border-bottom: 10px solid rgb(121, 0, 0);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;

}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 100px;
}

nav ul li{
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: rgb(121, 0, 0);
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}


nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #000;
}

.toggle {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background: rgb(121, 0, 0);
  text-align: right;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2rem;
  display: none;
}


.ul-list {
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#link-menu {
  margin-right: 10%;
}

#phone {
  margin-left: 10%;
}

nav .ul-list .social-btn li:nth-child(1) {
  padding-right: 0px;
}

nav .ul-list .social-btn li:nth-child(2) {
  padding-left: 7px;
}

.social-btn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}

i.fab.fa-facebook-square {
  color: #3b5992;
}

i.fab.fa-instagram {
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 30% 107%, #fdf497 0%, #fdf497 5%, #fd5949 45%, #d6249f 60%, #285AEB 90%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
          /* Also define standard property for compatibility */
          background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

/* Slider */
.slider {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: #1f1f1f;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  border-bottom: 10px solid rgb(121, 0, 0);
}

.slider > * {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #1f1f1f;
  animation: slide 12s infinite;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slide:nth-child(1) {
  left: 0%;
  animation-delay: -1s;
  background-image: url(img/slide1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide:nth-child(2) {
  left: 100%;
  animation-delay: 3s;
  background-image: url(img/slide2.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.slide:nth-child(3) {
  left: 100%;
  animation-delay: 7s;
  background-image: url(img/slide3.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}


.slide p {
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 350px;
  color: rgb(121, 0, 0);
  background: 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  opacity: 0.84;
  backdrop-filter: blur(30px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(30px);
  padding-top: 20px;
  z-index: 4;
}

.slide p span {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: #000;
}

.btn {
    background-color:transparent;
    border:3px solid rgb(121, 0, 0);;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:rgb(121, 0, 0);
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    padding:5px 30px;
  text-decoration:none;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color:transparent;
  color: #000;
  border:3px solid #000;
}
.btn:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}



@keyframes slide {
  0% { left: 100%; width: 100%; opacity: 1;}
  6.667% { left: 0%;}
  33.334% { left: 0%;}
  40% { left: -100%; width: 100%; opacity: 1;} 
  40.0001% { left: -100%; width: 0%; opacity: 0;}
  100% { left: 100%; width: 0%; opacity: 1;}
}

/* Prolog */
.prolog {
  text-align: center;
  color: #F2F2F2;
  margin: 10%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  margin-top: 102.5vh;
}

.prolog p {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

/* Newslatters */
.newslatters {
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  color: #F2F2F2;
}

.newslatters form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1% 35%;
  margin-top: 0%;
  color: #F2F2F2;
}

.newslatters p {
  margin: 0.5% 0%;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.newslatters h2 {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
}
 

.newslatters form input.email {
  margin: 1% 0;
  padding: 2% 0%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1rem;
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
}

.newslatters form input.email:active {
  border: 3px solid #000;
}


.newslatters form input.submit {
  margin: 1% 25%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  border: 3px solid rgb(121, 0, 0);
  padding: 1.3% 0%;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
  font-size: 1rem;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px transparent;
}

.newslatters form input:hover {
  border: 3px solid #000;
}

/* Footer */
footer {
  border-top: 5px solid rgb(121, 0, 0);
  margin-top: 2%;
}

footer .author {
  padding: 0.8% 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #F2F2F2;
}

footer .author a{
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #F2F2F2;
}

footer .author a:hover{
  color: rgb(121, 0, 0);
}

i.fas.fa-heart {
  color: rgb(121, 0, 0);
}

/* Media Query */
@media (max-width: 1440px) {
  nav ul li{
    font-size: 1.3rem;
  }

  nav ul {
    margin: 0 50px;
  }

}

@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  nav ul {
    margin: 0 10px;
  }

  nav ul li{
    font-size: 1rem;
  }

  footer .author {
    padding: 1.5% 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: #F2F2F2;
  }
  
}

@media (max-width: 1023px) {
  .toggle {
    display: block;
  }

  .kolecko {
    display: none;
  }

  .active {
    display: block;
  }

  .ul-list {
    display: flex;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
  }

  #link-menu {
    margin-right: 0%;
    height: 280px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
  }
  
  #phone {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }

  #phone li:nth-child(2) {
    border-bottom: none;
    padding-top: 20px;
  }

  #phone .social-btn li:nth-child(1) {
    border-bottom: none;
    padding-right: 7px;
  }

  #phone .social-btn li:nth-child(2){
    border-bottom: none;
    padding-top: 0px;
  }

  .social-btn {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  
  .logo {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: -400px;
  }
  
 
  nav {
    height: auto;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    border-bottom: 10px solid rgb(121, 0, 0);
    z-index:1;
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-content: flex-end;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    
  }
  
  nav ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-content: flex-end;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px 0px;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }
  
  nav ul li{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: rgb(121, 0, 0);
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    line-height: 1.4;
    border-bottom: 1px #000 solid;
  }
  
  nav ul li:nth-child(2) {
    margin-right: 0%;
  }
  
  nav ul li:nth-child(3) {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
  
  .slide p {
    margin-top: 250px;
  }

  .prolog {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }

  .newslatters form {
    margin: 1% 20%;
    font-size: 1rem;
  }

  .newslatters p {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }

  .newslatters form input.submit {
    padding: 1.3% 2%;
  }

}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-xxzQGERXS00kBmZW/6qxqJPyxW3UR0BPsL4c8ILaIWXva5kFi7TxkIIaMiKtqV1Q" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <div class="toggle">
    <i class="fa fa-bars menu" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
  <nav>
    <div class="ul-list">
      <ul id="link-menu">
        <li><a href="#" class="menu-link1"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Domů</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="menu-link2"><i class="fas fa-car"></i> Pronájem</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="menu-link3"><i class="fas fa-dollar-sign"></i> Prodej</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul id="phone">
        <li><a href="#" class="menu-link4"><i class="fas fa-mobile-alt"></i> Kontakt</a></li>
        <li><i class="fas fa-phone-square-alt"></i> +420 123456789</li>
        <div class="social-btn">
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="menu-container">
    <div class="kolecko">
    </div>
    <img src="css/img/logo.png" class="logo">
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="slider">
      <div class="slide">
        <p>MB A35 AMG 2019 AeroPacket <br><span>Můžeš mě mít již od 4999 Kč</span><br><a href="#" class="btn">Pronajmout</a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <p>Audi A7 V6T 2017 <br><span>Můžeš mě mít již od 4999 Kč</span><br><a href="#" class="btn">Pronajmout</a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <p>Audi A3 2017 <br><span>Můžeš mě mít již od 4999 Kč</span><br><a href="#" class="btn">Pronajmout</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="prolog">
      <h1>Overcars s.r.o. - Půjčovna a prodejna luxusních automobilů</h1>
      <p>Jsme malá začínající firma se zaměřením na pronájem a prodej vozů. Půjčujeme od levných vozů až po vozy luxusní! Naše vozy jsou s pravidelným servisem a ve 100% stavu. Řídíme se motem náš zákazník náš pán. Dokážeme zprostředkovat pronájem i prodej vozidel na míru.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="newslatters">
      <h2>Chceš vědět, co se u nás děje?</h2>
      <p>Přihlaš se k odběru novinek!</p>
      <form action="#">
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" class="email">
        <input type="submit" value="Odebírat" class="submit">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <div class="author">
      <p>Build with <i class="fas fa-heart"></i> by <a href="https://gmwebs.cz/">GMWebs</a></p>
    </div>
  </footer>
```

Can somebody help me please?

Thank you in advance for the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is definitely an issue with `z-index`.

You can simply add this CSS to your `nav`:

```
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
```

And remove the `z-index: -1` from the `.slider` element.